# Only createdAt column in join table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

By default, sequelize will create createdAt and updatedAt columns in join table for many to many relationships but I only want to use `createdAt` column and set it automatically when row created.

custom `UserJob` model:

```
const UserJob = sequelize.define('UserJob', {
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
UserJob.beforeCreate((userJob, options) => {
    console.log('before create');
    userJob.createdAt = new Date();
});
return UserJob;
```

Associations:

```
User.belongsToMany(models.Job, {through: UserJob, foreignKey: 'user_id'});
Job.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: UserJob, foreignKey: 'job_id'});
```

it doesn't set createdAt, what should I do?

Comment: is it not getting date ? or what is inserting in 'userJob.createdAt'

Comment: before create not being called and createdAt is null in the table!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [sequelize suggests](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration), if you don't want a particular timestamp
You should define your model as

```
const Foo = sequelize.define('foo', { /* bla */ 
  { // don't forget to enable timestamps! 
  timestamps: true,
  // I don't want createdAt 
  createdAt: false,
  // I want updatedAt to actually be called updateTimestamp
  updatedAt: 'updateTimestamp'
})
```

So for your case, you could set `updatedAt` to false, that way the column won't exist.
And would be more cleaner than using a hook.